# Does spline animation work for svg opacity, and if so, how?

Tags: animation, svg

In the following SVG document, the first rectangle's opacity is animated using `calcMode=discrete`, and flashes on and off as I would expect. The second rectangle is supposed to be animated using `calcMode=linear`, but no animation is visible in Chrome or Firefox.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 400 500">
    <rect width="300" height="100" transform="translate(50,50)" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
       <animate attributeName="opacity" attributeType="XML" dur="1.2s" values="0.1; 1.0; 0.1" keyTimes="0; 0.33; 0.67" calcMode="discrete" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </rect>
   <rect width="300" height="100" transform="translate(50,250)" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
       <animate attributeName="opacity" attributeType="XML" dur="1.2s" values="0.1; 1.0; 0.1" keyTimes="0; 0.33; 0.67" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </rect>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aJUnZ/

Is my animation not defined correctly, is this not supported by SVG, or is it simply not implemented by browsers yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SVG Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#ValueAttributes)...

*For linear and spline animation, the first time value in the list must be 0, and the last time value in the list must be 1. The key time associated with each value defines when the value is set; values are interpolated between the key times.*

Your final keyTimes value is not 1 and therefore your animation isn't valid. Change it to 1 and it will work.

Comment: I knew it was something in the spec I was missing. Thanks!